# apt-get update stuck in my K8s, fail to install any tool to debug

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubernetes-helm

I am new in K8s world and I am using helm to install the stable/mysql template then I would like to test it.

I run below to spawn a new ubuntu container as mysql client. However the apt-get update stuck at "Waiting for headers" always.

```
kubectl run -i --tty ubuntu --image=ubuntu:16.04 --restart=Never -- bash -il

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get update
0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
```

I think it is network issue, but I am not able to install any tool to debug as the apt-get not work.

I tried couple of ways like modifying the /etc/resolv.conf, but it seems it doesn't help.

Anyone can share me some lights about how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like you are running behind a proxy, or that your CNI is busted; can you `curl` to _any_ Internet host from inside your cluster?

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLDaniel! Actually the container can not install anything because the apt-get hang. What I can do is to spawn another busybox container, and I was able to ping www.google.com inside that container. Do you have any more suggestion?

Comment: I finally making it work after following https://askubuntu.com/questions/109673/how-to-use-apt-get-via-http-proxy-like-this to setup proxy for apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this to setup the proxy will make it work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/109673/how-to-use-apt-get-via-http-proxy-like-this

Add below content to file /etc/apt/apt.conf.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.server.port:8080";
```